# Valgrind test for Extending Python with C

Tags: python, c, valgrind

I want to check memory leak in my C extending modules for Python3 with valgrind.
I downloaded the valgrind suppression file (http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/valgrind-python.supp) and uncomment the lines for PyObject_Free and PyObject_Realloc in this file.
Then I run valrgind test:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --suppressions=valgrind-python.supp \
                                      python3 -E -tt ./my_python_script.py
```

But, I get many errors if I even execute just "print('hello world')", e.g:

```
==13735== ERROR SUMMARY: 604 errors from 45 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

What's wrong? Why so many errors? How can I check my apps?

```
$ uname -a
Linux mongo-r4 3.8.0-31-generic #46~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 11 18:21:16 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ valgrind --version
valgrind-3.10.0.SVN

$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.0
```

Comment: My best guess is that the python-executable is extremely buggy, but no-one dares to state it :) Anyhow, I have had the same question for some time as well. Nevertheless, when I executed `echo '<?php echo "hello";  ?>' | valgrind php5.6`, valgrind stated `vex: the 'impossible' happened`. `javac` and `java` on a simple hello-world gave me 783120 and 70600 respectively. So software standards are pretty low these days? Or maybe the common denominator, valgrind, is to blame.